# Getting partial R2 values from a Multivariate Linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, correlation, lm

I have a linear model with multiple predictor variables, and I would like to know the partial R2 values for each predictor. I see the partial p-values in the `summary` output but not the partial R2s. Do i need to download additional packages for this?

```
df <- mtcars

mod.mlr <-summary( lm(mpg ~., data = df))
```

Comment: It is probably easier to use an additional package like `rsq` for that, but you can always write a function yourself if you feel inclined. For an interesting discussion around this topic, including the relevant math, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64010/importance-of-predictors-in-multiple-regression-partial-r2-vs-standardized.

Comment: In addition to @user12728748's hints, package `{ppcor}` is mentioned a couple of times in this SO thread on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+partial+correlation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `partial_r2` of the R package [sensemakr](https://carloscinelli.com/sensemakr/) to compute the partial R2.

```r
library(sensemakr)
#> See details in:
#> Carlos Cinelli and Chad Hazlett (2020). Making Sense of Sensitivity: Extending Omitted Variable Bias. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series B (Statistical Methodology).

df <- mtcars

model <- lm(mpg ~., data = df)

partial_r2(model)
#>  (Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp         drat           wt 
#> 0.0201591032 0.0005412271 0.0258677677 0.0443187825 0.0109107458 0.1548024114 
#>         qsec           vs           am         gear         carb 
#> 0.0566909597 0.0010844617 0.0667336071 0.0090902140 0.0027495993
```